# How independent can a component be before it becomes an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that React apps should follow the following principle:

*Data flows down, events bubble up*

However, I find it quite cumbersome to send events like mouse-clicks from child components all the way up to the root and then send the new state all the way back down. I understand this method makes sense if multiple components are affected by the new state - but consider the following example:

```
var PSMenu = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isOpen: false     
        }
    },
    handleMenuClick: function(){
        console.log("hello worldd");
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className={this.state.isOpen ? "ps-menu ps-menu-open" : "ps-menu"}>
                <div className="ps-menu-button" onClick={this.handleMenuClick}>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Here, I have a menu class that has a button sticking out. The button is a toggle for opening and closing the menu. Is it okay that I handle the `onClick` of the `ps-menu-button` div within the `PSMenu` component? The root component has no idea this occurred but it doesn't matter since it shouldn't care.

If this example does indeed follow the React paradigm, consider the following. What if the div `ps-menu-button` was not a regular div but a React component called `PSMenuButton` nested inside `PSMenu`. Can I have just the `PSMenu` and `PSMenuButton` talk between each other without the parent knowing?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I don't think "Data flows down, events bubble up" implies that every piece of data or every event has to touch every layer of the UI;  rather, it's to remind you of the direction of flow.  If, in your example, `PSMenuButton` sent an event up, and `PSMenu` handled it, it doesn't need to go any further.  But you would never want to design an event where `PSMenu` was telling `PSMenuButton` to do something.

Comment: Thank you, that makes me feel much better.